# How to Change Port no. of GeoServer Running as Service

Tags: geoserver, xml, jetty

I installed my geoServer as a service on port 8080. However, I need to use this port for some other service and have been trying to move it to port 7000 instead but I can't find a way to change the port number. I have tried to add in the option on startup.bat

```
-Djetty.port=7000
```

and modified the jetty.xml file to

```
<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="7000"/></Set>
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

go to this link, hope it will be helpful:
https://www.esdm.co.uk/how-to-change-the-port-for-geoserver-on-windows-with-jetty